# how to alert a message in the browser using php cron file

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, cron

I am having a php file that runs every 1 minute through crontab. The file contains a variable, on checking the value of that variable, I want to alert a message to the user in the browser.

I tried using javascript alert function but it did not worked. On searching on google I found that cron file does not support javascript as js run on client and cron on server side.

They also suggested to us node.js, but node.js does not seem to have alert function. I am new to node.js and not getting how to alert message in the browser from a php cron file using node.js.

Need HELP!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If your php script is started per cron, there is no browser who can get any message. Only if a browser request has started the script, you can put any message in the response.

Comment: Yes, my script is started by a browser request.

Comment: And what is started by cron? When a cronjob is started, there is no way to inform possibly existing browsers which possibly show any page from your server. It may be thousands. And there is no connection. After a browser gets a response, the connection is closed and the browser is unreachable, even if you know his address.
The only way would be the answer of @Muhammed. The cron job saves a status anywhere, and the *next* browser request will show it. But only, if any browser does a request.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you create a table in database like `notification`
fields:
`id,type,message, date_created`.

Then insert record into this table from your cron job file.

In PHP or Nodejs check this table after 1 minute or 2 minute, if there is new record then get it and show alert message .

Like you want to show your notification in header.

```
<script>

//make ajax request here to php file.and then append notification div

</script>

<div id="notification"></div>
```

**Note!**

It is an idea how you can implement this logic :)))

Answer (score 0):

There are two way's you can you can get the solution.

1) you need to create the Notification functionality which will notify the client browser.

2) You need to implement the socket programming by using socket you can send the message to all the active browser as well as you can filter that also.